# Unix Command to Delete all files in a directory but preserve the directory

Tags: unix

I am looking for a unix command to delete all files within a directory without deleting the directory itself. (note the directory does not contain subdirectories).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
rm -i <directory>/*
```

this should do the trick

EDIT: added -i just in case (safety first). directory should be a full or relative path (e.g. `/tmp/foo` or `../trash/stuffs`)

Comment: Is there a way to delete without supplying a path? I.e from the directory you cd-d to?

Comment: of course, you can always cd to your directory and then perform a "rm -i *" please note that the -i flag will force confirmation of each deletion, is there just for safety (nasty things will occurr if you misplace a / in your commandline and you provide a -r flag...)

Comment: I'm using rm -r * but it's asking for a confirmation on each file deletion. To stop this it's rm -rf * yes? Trying to delete all from current directory.

Comment: -r perform recursive deletion, -f forces deletion, assuming the rm command has not been aliased, I'd go with a rm -f *

Comment: The rm command is currently aliased as 'rm -i'. Will this affect the forced deletion?

Comment: `rm -i` sounds like a horrible suggestion if someone wants to delete "all" files, at least if it's more than let's say 3 files. Nobody likes to hammer the y key to confirm every single deletion.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
rm -r yourDirectory/*
```

it deletes all file inside the "yourdirectory" directory

Comment: Is there a way to delete without supplying a path? I.e from the directory you cd-d to?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to a unix newbie to use the -r switch, what if OP misplaces a / on the command line ?

Comment: Understandable but the issue is that i am clearing out spam from the remote qmail folder. There is thousands of messages to clear so I need a practical way of doing it without confirmation on each deletion.

Comment: I assume He wants to clear a folder, which means deleting sub folders

Comment: There are no subfolders as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @Amxx as long as someone puts a wrong / somewhere on the command line. Reading the question I assume OP is not familiar with unix/linux command line, so I think it's better suggest fairly safe commands. The -r in coinjunction with the -f flag can lead to very nasty situations (after all we don't know how's the box is configured, if he's operating as root or the likes)

Comment: That's why I never told im to use -rf, in my opinion, -r without -f isn't so dangerous, and sometimes newcomers wonder why rm doesnt delete subfolder.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find /path/to/your/folder/ -delete` to delete everything within that folder.

While a wildcard `rm` would braek with too many files ("Argument list too long"), this works no matter how many files there are.

You can also make it delete only files but preserve any subdirectories:

```
find /path/to/your/folder/ -type f -delete
```

You could also specify any other criteria `find` supports to restrict the "results".

Comment: This is the best answer as it preserve the directory structure.

Comment: This is closest to the correct answer because every other proposed solution ignores the hidden files (prefixed with '.').  As it stands however the `find` command does act on command line arguments as well unless you specify `-mindepth 1`.  With that addition the solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

you can remove all the files form the current directory using `rm *`
if you want to remove from a specific directory, type `rm /path/*`

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the directory where you want to remove all the files then the following command works fine:

```
rm *
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Delete all file as well as all Directory that means all things then try this:

```
rm -rf *
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rm -r /UrDir/*.*`
This would ignore the files in the sub-directories

Comment: Just trying to improve readability, but noted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you,

```
rm path/*
```

eg:

```
rm ../mydir/*
```

In this command,if `mydir` has any sub_directory! it'll raise error an message and skip that sub_directory and remove rest of the files in main directory.